# Can't compare lsb_release result to string in Bash

Tags: command-line, string, test, lsb-release

I'm doing something wrong on the string comparison below. It works if I set a variable and compare that, but I can't copy the value to a string. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
$ if [ "$(lsb_release -i)" = "Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseClient" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
$ lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseClient
$ var="$(lsb_release -i)"
$ if [ "$(lsb_release -i)" = "$var" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I suggest `-is`:

```
if [ $(lsb_release -is) = "Debian" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the output from `lsb_release -i` uses a tab instead of space:

```
lsb_release -i|od -c
0000000   D   i   s   t   r   i   b   u   t   o   r       I   D   :  \t
0000020   R   e   d   H   a   t   E   n   t   e   r   p   r   i   s   e
0000040   S   e   r   v   e   r  \n
```

Notice the `\t` at the end of the first line. Include that in your comparison string, and it will succeed:

```
if [ "$(lsb_release -i)" = $'Distributor ID:\tRedHatEnterpriseServer' ]; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a good solution, but this works:

```
if [ "$(echo $(lsb_release -i))" = "Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseClient" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

Comment: Agreed: not a good solution.